# summary statistics for a variable based on another variable

Tags: r, structure, summary

Im trying to find that how many x values in ID where some values are repeated then based on the new result find the min, max, IQR, and median in overall ;

```
ID <- c("ID004", "ID004", "ID004", "ID004", "ID006", "ID006", "ID006", "ID006", "ID006", "ID006", "ID006", "ID006", "ID006", "ID006", "ID006", "ID009", "ID009", "ID009", "ID009", "ID009", "ID009", "ID020", "ID020")
D <- c("CMP-001", "CMP-001","CMP-001","CMP-001","CMP-001", "CMP-001","CMP-002", "CMP-002", "CMP-002", "CMP-003", "CMP-003", "CMP-003", "CMP-004", "CMP-004", "CMP-004", "CMP-001", "CMP-001", "CMP-001", "CMP-001", "CMP-002", "CMP-002", "CMP-001", "CMP-001")
X <- c(3,3,3,3,1,1,3,3,3,1,1,1,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,2,2,2,2)
data <- data.frame(ID, D, X)
```

we first find how many x values per ID as;

```
ID.       No. of X values
ID004.          1
ID006.          4
ID009           2
ID020           1
```

then based on this result we should get the following result;

```
                          Min.    Median.    Max.     IQR
Number of X per ID        1         1.5        4      3-1
```

I think we need to create a new variable which include values of X per ID. then find the summery statistics for the new variable

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this answers:

```
> data %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(Min = min(X), Median = median(X), Max = max(X), IQR = IQR(X), No_of_X_values = length(rle(X)[[1]]))
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 4 x 6
  ID      Min Median   Max   IQR No_of_X_values
  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>          <int>
1 ID004     3      3     3   0                1
2 ID006     1      3     4   2.5              4
3 ID009     2      4     4   1.5              2
4 ID020     2      2     2   0                1
>
```

Can store the ID and No of x values in a new dataframe and take summary statistics for No. of x values:

```
> x_values <- data %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(No_of_X_values = length(rle(X)[[1]]))
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
> x_values
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  ID    No_of_X_values
  <chr>          <int>
1 ID004              1
2 ID006              4
3 ID009              2
4 ID020              1
> summary(x_values$No_of_X_values)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    1.0     1.0     1.5     2.0     2.5     4.0
```

Comment: Thank you for trying but its not the right answer, I think we need to create a new variable which include values of X per ID. then find the summery statistics for the new variable.

Comment: Ok, have added variable that has count of each variable in X, if you need the result in a different format, can you please share some sample output.

Comment: Did you want summary stats over the column `count_per_X` in the answer above by @KarthikS?   Try `data %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(n=n()) %>% summary()`

Comment: the variable you added should match the first result in my question. (i.e, ID004 has only 1 value which is 3 but repeated, second ID006 has 4 values which are (1,3,1,4) etc

Comment: You mean **unique values** in X by ID?   `data %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise( unique=unique(X)) %>% summary()`

Comment: @KarthikS thank you, this is the first step Im looking for. Thus, I wanna find the min, median and max for the new variable you got (No_of_X_values)